# Simple jQuery Syntax and Concatenation within the jQuery Selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quick question, is this code possible?

```
function respond (primary_id) {
var answer = $('id_of_' + primary_id).val();    
}
```

I've tested it out but the error produced does not directly point to this line of code, but another that is using this variable answer so I can't be sure if this is causing the problem or something else. If this can't work, then what is an alternative?

Comment: Don't forget the # on id selectors =)

Comment: Silly me. I forgot to add the #.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('id_of_' + primary_id)
```

Would point to all elements:

```
<id_of_xxx>
```

Which don't exist in any version of HTML I've seen...

If you're looking for an element with that ID,

```
$('#id_of_' + primary_id)
```

Would be the way to go.

Also, don't forget to return the value:

```
function respond (primary_id) {
     var answer = $('id_of_' + primary_id).val();    
     return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find it very easily on http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Here, you should use '#' before the element Id like this.

```
function respond (primary_id) {
      var answer = $('#id_of_' + primary_id).val();    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are selecting an element based on an id it should be preceded by a # so your code should be

```
var answer = $('#id_of_' + primary_id).val();
```